# hyperbolic groups are centerless (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, geometric-group-theory

I am looking for a reference for the statement: *Any word hyperbolic group has trivial centre* (which seemed to be implicit in some old math overflow answer I am reading). I cannot seem to find it by a standard search, so I am asking here for a reference. Thanks.

Comment: This is almost true: The right statement is that center of any nonelementary hyperbolic group is finite. Examples to think about: $F_k\times {\mathbb Z}_n$ is a hyperbolic group, $k\ge 0, n\ge 1$.

Comment: This seems to follow from the fact that in hyperbolic groups, infinite cyclic subgroups are finite index in their centralizer.  So once you rule out torsion and the hyperbolic group $\mathbb{Z}$ you're done.

Comment: Probably the MO answer you (don't) refer to assumes the hyperbolic group is torsion-free (and not cyclic).

Comment: @YCor, Thanks, indeed it does. In fact I am interested in the fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic manifold, so these properties are automatic. The reason I don't reference is because it is somehow embedded in some long discussion of some other issue and I didn't want to waste people time (I cannot even find the question now, sorry).

Comment: The initial reference for this result is Gromov's initial monograph on hyperbolic groups.